# Unable to operate servo with rosserial_arduino

Tags: ros-kinetic, rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ros kinetic on ubuntu 16.04.
I'm able to perform the hello world code from rosserial tutorials http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World
However not being able to operate the servo example.
Any ideas? no error on Arduino IDE. After i perform the test on the terminal
roscore
rostopic pub servo std_msgs/UInt16  8

the terminal output:publishing and latching message. Press ctrl-C to terminate
Nothing after that

```
/*
 * rosserial Servo Control Example

#if (ARDUINO >= 100)
 #include <Arduino.h>
#else
 #include <WProgram.h>

#endif

#include <Servo.h> 
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/UInt16.h>

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

Servo servo;

void servo_cb( const std_msgs::UInt16& cmd_msg){
  servo.write(cmd_msg.data); //set servo angle, should be from 0-180  
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH-digitalRead(13));  //toggle  led  
}


ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::UInt16> sub("servo", servo_cb);

void setup(){
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

nh.initNode();

nh.subscribe(sub);
  
servo.attach(9); //attach it to pin 9
}

void loop(){
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341697/unable-to-operate-servo-with-rosserial_arduino/) by [alam121](https://answers.ros.org/users/50900/alam121/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`delay(1)` is a very small delay. You may want to try and change it to something a little higher. I've seen previous Q&As where using a larger delay makes things work better.

Not saying it will solve your problem though. Just something to keep in mind.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alam121](https://answers.ros.org/users/50900/alam121/) on 2020-01-14**:
This actually worked. I'm not sure why i did not think of it earlier. Many thanks!